# problems when deploying WebDSL app to Tomcat v6.0

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, web, eclipse-plugin, tomcat6

I get the following error while deploying my webDSL app to Tomcat v6.0 using the WebDSl eclipse plugin

```
    type Exception report

    message 

    description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

    exception 

   javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet mainservlet threw exception
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


    root cause 

    org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started
org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.rollback(JDBCTransaction.java:179)
utils.DispatchServlet.tryLoadGlobalsAndPerformInit(DispatchServlet.java:31)
utils.DispatchServlet.init(DispatchServlet.java:39)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

It stopped working last evening.
I tried rebooting that didn't work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'Transaction not successfully started' error indicates an issue with the database connection. Try logging into MySQL with the command-line client to verify that MySQL is running and the credentials are correct. After logging in, check that the database exists.

For further help you can also visit IRC (#webdsl channel on irc.freenode.net), ask on the mailing list (https://mailman.st.ewi.tudelft.nl/listinfo/webdsl), or post issues at http://yellowgrass.org/project/WebDSL.